# if condition with find command in Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

I am struggling to write a find command in the if condition, Let me share my requirement first.
i have a list of files in a file named /tmp/fmxfile

```
cat /tmp/fmxfile
/fmx/eng/hint.fmx
/pll/case.pll
/plx/eng/case.plx
```

i am writing a for loop above file, (to look for each file in the different path if condition passes)
In the first IF condition first i want to check if file is there in that path
In the Second IF condition i want to find if that file is modified in last 5 mins , if it is true then cp that file to the /tmp path.

```
cd /apps/common/bau/base/
for file in `cat /tmp/fmxfileslist`
do
if [ -f $file ]
then
    echo "File '${file}' found in $(pwd) path and created on $(date +%D)."
    if [ $(find $file -mmin -5 -type f) ="true" ];
    then
    cp -a $file /tmp/basefmxfiles
    ls -lrt | grep /tmp/basefmxfiles
    else 
    echo "But the file is not modified in last 5 minutes"
    fi
else
echo "$0: File '${file}' not found."
fi
done
```

Comment: 1.) Your described list of files was `/tmp/fmxfile`, but your script reads filenames from `/tmp/fmxfileslist`. Was that just an error in writing the question, and if not, what's in `/tmp/fmxfileslist`? 2.) If your script actually reads `/tmp/fmxfile`, the `$file` will refer to those exact absolute paths listed in that file, not to anything under `/apps/common/bau/base`. So your first `if` will look into a wrong place and your first `echo` will tell lies. 3.) `date +%D` will just show the current date, not the creation date of any file. 4.) `find` will never output "true" when used like that.

Comment: This question seems like homework exercise. If you get an answer for free, what will happen in a final exam when you'll have to write a different script with no outside help?

Comment: can you please help me to correct the script , I want to search for the files of  /tmp/fmxfile  in this  path /apps/common/bau/base and check if that file is modified in last 5 mins  then copy those specific file to /tmp/basefmxfiles

Comment: So for the first file, do you want to check a) *exactly* `/apps/common/bau/base/fmx/eng/hint.fmx` only, or b) *exactly* `/apps/common/bau/base/hint.fmx` only, or c) `hint.fmx` in `/apps/common/bau/base` or any sub-directory of it?

Answer (score 2):

Some comments over your code (assuming it's meant to be in `sh` syntax):

> ```
> cd /apps/common/bau/base/
> ```

You're not checking the exit status of `cd`, so if it fails, you'll carry on running the rest of the script in the current working directory, whatever it is.

> ```
> for file in `cat /tmp/fmxfileslist`
> ```

That uses split+glob on top of the deprecated `` `...` `` form of command substitution, while it looks like you want to iterate over the lines of the file for which the syntax would be:

```
while IFS= read -r file <&3; do
  ...
done 3< /tmp/fmxfileslist
```

(or should it be `/tmp/fmxfile` instead)?

Also note that using files with fixed names in world-writable directories such as `/tmp` is bad practice from a security standpoint.

Also, none of the path in your sample list are relative, so does it matter what the current working directory is? Or should the list be:

```
fmx/eng/hint.fmx
pll/case.pll
plx/eng/case.plx
```

instead? Or should the leading `/` be stripped or a `.` inserted  before it?

> ```
> do
> if [ -f $file ]
> ```

That's using split+glob again over the expansion of `$file`, which doesn't make sense. You likely meant `[ -f "$file" ]` if the intention was to check that the file exists, is accessible to you and can be determined to be *regular* (not directory, fifo, device, socket...) after symlink resolution.

> ```
> then
>     echo "File '${file}' found in $(pwd) path and created on $(date +%D)."
> ```

`$(pwd)` this time using  the modern form of command substitution can be written `$PWD` in POSIX shells. `date +%D` prints the current date. To print the last modification time of `$file`, assuming GNU `date`, you can use the `-r` option. `%D` gives dates in `mm/dd/yy` format which is very ambiguous and doesn't give any information of time nor timezone. `$(date -r "$file" +%FT%T%z || echo UNKNOWN)`.

Also note that `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data. Use `printf '%s\n' "..."` instead.

> ```
>     if [ $(find $file -mmin -5 -type f) ="true" ];
> ```

Again, using split+glob on both `$file` and the output of `find`. You're also missing a space after the `=` so the `[` command won't see a `=` comparison operator argument but a bogus `=true` one.

Also, as `find` will print the file paths that it finds, it will only ever print `true` if `$file` is `true` (`true` followed by any number of newline characters would also work as trailing newlines are stripped by command substitution, but as you're reading your `fmxfileslist` file one line at a time, that cannot happen; IOW your `fmxfileslist` file cannot include arbitrary file names).

Also note that `find` will choke on file names starting with `-` (also on `!`, `(`...).

And `-type f` returns false for symlinks to regular files while the `[ -f "$file" ]` above would return true. You'd need the GNU specific `-xtype f` to get consistency between the two or use  `-L` to also check the modification time of the target of the symlink (as `date -r` also does), so, assuming GNU `find` 4.9 or  newer:

```
if [ "$(
  printf '%s\0' "$file" | find -L -files0-from - -prune -type f -mmin -5 -printf true)" = true ]
then
  printf '%s\n' "$file is found to be regular after symlink resolution and has been last modified within the last 5 minutes or in the future"
fi
```

Here passing the file path NUL-delimited on `find`'s stdin (which it gets from there with `-files0-from -`, the part needing 4.9 or newer), instead of as argument to avoid the choking issue mentioned above.¹

> ```
>     then
>     cp -a $file /tmp/basefmxfiles
> ```

Again, non-sensical split+glob, and you're also missing the `--` option delimiter. If `/tmp/basefmxfiles` didn't exist as a directory beforehand, that would create it as a copy of `$file` instead, so it's a good habit to append a `/` to the end of the target directory to avoid that (or here since you're already using GNUisms, use GNU `cp`'s `-t` option):

```
cp -a -- "$file" /tmp/basefmxfiles/
cp -at /tmp/basefmxfiles -- "$file"
```

> ```
>     ls -lrt | grep /tmp/basefmxfiles
> ```

`ls -lrt` lists the contents of the current working directory (meant to be `/apps/common/bau/base/` here), and the only way to have `/tmp/basefmxfiles` in that output is if there's some:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 1 May 17 18:11 somelink -> foo/tmp/basefmxfilesbar
```

symlink in there, so it's unclear what you meant to do with that command.

> ```
>     else 
>     echo "But the file is not modified in last 5 minutes"
>     fi
> else
> echo "$0: File '${file}' not found."
> ```

That's the `else` part of your `[ -f $file ]`, which checks whether `$file` is a *regular* file, so the error (which should go to stderr) should rather be:

```
printf>&2 '%s\n' "$0: File '$file' not found as a regular file."
```

Here, you could do every thing with `find` (again assuming GNU `find` 4.9 or above):

```
cd /apps/common/bau/base || exit
tr '\n' '\0' < /tmp/fmxfileslist |
  find -L -files0-from -                                    \
    -prune                                                  \
    -type f                                                 \
    -printf '%p regular and last modified on %TFT%TT%Tz\n'  \
    '('                                                     \
       -mmin -5 -printf '%p regular and mtime > -5min\n' -o \
          -printf '%p regular but older\n'                  \
    ')' -o -printf '%p not a regular files\n'
```

For files that `find` can't access, it will print an error message on stderr.

Or you could use `zsh` instead of `sh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
cd /apps/common/bau/base || exit

          files=( ${(f)"$(</tmp/fmxfileslist)"} )
       regulars=( $^files(N-.)                  )
recent_regulars=( $^regulars(N-m-5)             )
 older_regulars=( ${regulars:|recent_regulars}  )
   non_regulars=( ${files:|regulars}            )

     accessible=( $^files(N-^@)                 )
   inaccessible=( ${files:|accessible}          )
```

And for instance `print` the contents of those arrays `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn with `print -rC1 -- $array` or iterate over them with `for file ($array) something with $file` (there's no split+glob over unquoted parameter expansions in zsh, so it's fine to leave them unquoted there).

To get the last modification time of a file, before or after symlink resolution you can use its `stat` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -F %FT%T%z -H after -- $file &&
  stat -LF %FT%T%z -H before -- $file &&
  print -r "mtime before symlink resolution: $before[mtime]; after: $after[mtime]"
```

---

<sup>¹ On BSDs, you can use the `find -f "$file" ...` syntax instead.</sup>

Comment: master class in shell scripting!! Archemar bow

Comment: Hi Please share the command with echo command below
if [ "$(
  printf '%s\0' "$file" | find -L -files0-from - -prune -type f -mmin -5 -printf true)" = true ]
then
  printf '%s\n' "$file is found to be regular after symlink resolution and has been last modified within the last 5 minutes or in the future"
fi

Comment: @afrin, not sure what you mean. `echo` is not a command that should be used to output arbitrary data. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803). With a UNIX compliant `echo` (like the builtin one in `bash` after `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo`), you could do `echo "$file\00\c"` to print the file's name NUL-delimited, but that  wouldn't work properly for file names that contain backslash characters.

Comment: i want to execute this shell script in the Linux machines and it is not working with printf

Comment: @afrin, if it's not working, it's unlikely to be about `printf` which has been standard for decades. More likely your `find` version is too old or is not the GNU one. Check with `find --version`.